# Formatting GridView values based on decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formatting

I want to check all the values of a gridview and if there is no decimals I want to show only the integer part of the value, else if there is any decimals I want to show only two decimals. I use this but nothing...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        var p = Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
        e.Row.Cells[i].Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}", p);
    }                 
    }
```

example: if a value is 3.6666666 I want to show 3.66 and
if a value is 3.0000000 I want to show 3. Also If a Value is string do nothing.
Any suggestions?

I did it with asp code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="3P" SortExpression="3POINT_MADE">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("3POINT_MADE", "{0:0.##}") + "/" + Eval("3POINT_ATTEMPT", "{0:0.##}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DEFENSIVE_REBOUNDS"  DataFormatString="{0:0.##}" HeaderText="DR" SortExpression="DEFENSIVE_REBOUNDS" />
```

Is there any suggestion to do it with c# in behind code? I think that is better and has better performance.

Comment: Convert the text do double and not to int. You could try string.Format("{0:0.##}", p) -> for 3.000000 gives 3, for 3.66666666 rounds to 3.67 (if rounding is ok/acceptable). More about custom numeric formating can be found [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It gives me the error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Do you have empty cells? What values do you have in your cells? Use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then write value to the cell only if the result is true = ok.

Comment: I have these cells:   
First row:       Average 3 14,666666 3 0,666666666666667 3,0 3,7
Second row:      Total   3 44,000000 4,0 2,0           1,0   1,0

Answer (score 0):

`GridView1_RawDataBound` should be `GridView1_RowDataBound`